# How to access a function in a model outside the module in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm a magento newbie. I have two custom modules, let's say module A and module B. I need to access a function in a model in module A from module B.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Any php file in magento you can access a model using the below code,

```
Mage::getModel('modulename/model')->myfunction(param1,param2 ... etc);
```

Hope this is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

`Mage::getModel('modelA')->modelA_function();`

Comment: please don't add the direct code, just add at least one bit of line of explanation in words.